# Conditionally copy data from csv file to PostgreSQL table

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

Is there a way, using PL/pgSQL, to copy data from csv file to PostgreSQL table only if the file exists, something similar to this:

```
BEGIN
    IF file_exists(filename) THEN
        COPY table FROM 'filename' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: You could use `pg_stat_file()`  from here [File Operations](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-GENFILE). It needs superuser privileges by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try something like this:

```
select exists(select * from pg_ls_dir('directory_name') as file where file  = 'fileName');
```

but the directory should exists. [check this also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25413303/how-to-list-files-in-a-folder-from-inside-postgres)

Comment: Glad it helped I recommend you check [this source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88535/asking-for-someone-to-accept-your-answer) for inspiration

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly wahat I was looking for. For future lurkers, I decided to go with the simple for loop, so this way I will only copy the files that exist within certain directory to given tables:
`FOR row IN select pg_ls_dir('/data') LOOP  filename = row.pg_ls_dir;  tablename = replace(filename, '.csv', '');  filename = '/data/' || filename;  EXECUTE 'COPY ' || tablename || ' FROM ''' || filename || ''' DELIMITER '','' CSV HEADER'; END LOOP;`